# Efficiently VB Escape Character like @'String' in C#

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, escaping

C# have `@` symbol to quickly and efficiently escape a SQL command line string, is there any way to do the same thing in VB.Net ?

Comment: Since VB doesn't have the same type of inline character replacements as C#, why would it need such a facility?

Comment: VB strings are already like C# verbatim string literals.

Comment: I am working with a guy who is writing in VB and I am asking him to display the SQL command strings in the log (he says he is using printlog to dump info). He cannot get it to show up in the log file "no matter what he tries" and so I was thinking that maybe he needed to escape it or something. In the meantime he was using message boxes to display the SQL command string, but that obviously only works when debugging the problem, not as a permanent solution since his program runs as a service.

His "log" is actually an MSSQL table if that helps clarify anything...

Comment: If he's logging to an MSSQL table, make sure he's doing it either with parameterized SQL or LINQ. It's my guess that there's an SQL syntax error in the way (probably from the SQL command that's being logged); using parameters or LINQ avoids that and they're far better anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, VB.NET doesn't have an equivalent to C#'s @ symbol when used as a string escape character.

I'm guessing that he's not replacing out characters that would cause formatting issues. Ask him to replace CrLfs with a space.

Comment: Thanks.  This guy does not know how to do anything "too complicated" as he would put it and was asking me for the syntax to do so.  Thanks for the clear cut answer.  Parsing that out is going to be over his head and/or new territory for him at this juncture.  Thanks again.